# Take the content of an element in other element based on a class element

Tags: javascript, html

Here is an example

```
<p id="myid">
    <font>
        <font>000</font>
    </font>
</p>
```

I want to take the 000

I though something like this

```
document.getElementById("#myid").innerHTML
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You don't need `#` when you use `getElementById()`
2. You need to use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`.
3. Make sure your code runs when `DOM` is finished loading.

Code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  alert(document.getElementById('myid').innerText);
});
```

```html
<p id="myid">
  <font>
    <font>000</font>
  </font>
</p>
```

Comment: @Agata `$('.name.class-ID').attr('id')` Notice the `.` between both classes and there is no space